# Node.js - using tsoa or express to build REST API

Tags: node.js, typescript, rest, express, tsoa

I need to choose the architecture of the new nodejs project. This will be a REST API server with WebSockets.

Do you know any pros and cons o using this two libraries?
tsoa vs express?

Express is more common and stable library (I think).
With tsoa I can use typescript and controllers (cleaner code).

What would you recommend?

Comment: What stops you from using `typescript` in `express`? It supports TS

Comment: I would use express because it's easy to start with, also you can use TS with express in order to have more clean code, use DI and decorators to robust your api, if you want you can use this npm package that I have created to start with an template https://www.npmjs.com/package/@agutierrezt9410/express-ts-cli